# rmongo and query-ing

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongo

I have difficulty with writing query via rmongo ..

```
mongo <- mongoDbConnect(dbName="baba", host="inja.com",port='27017')
dbAuthenticate(mongo, 'alaki', 'dolaki')
dbShowCollections(mongo)
> Acol Bcol Ccol Dcol
```

now :

```
result = dbGetQuery(mongo, "settings", "{find_one()}",0,10)
> Error in .jcall(rmongo.object@javaMongo, "S", "dbGetQuery", collection,  : 
      com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
    {find_one()}
```

I appreciate if someone give me some hint and help me to make a table or R list from my database.

Comment: any reason for voting down ?!

Answer (score 3):

The query argument for `dbGetQuery()` should be the data you want to search for, not find_one().

The result of a dbGetQuery() will be a [Data Frame](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame).

Example usage:

```
# Find documents in "settings" collection (no query criteria); limit results to 10
result=dbGetQuery(mongo, "settings","{}",0,10)

# Find all documents that have a value of "blackbox" for the "widget" column
result=dbGetQuery(mongo, "settings","{'widget':'blackbox'}")
```

Comment: How do I query for an id field where I would need to search by 'key': ObjectId('....'). It is failing for me.

Comment: @KumarDeepak Can you post a separate question with example of the code you've tried and the error(s) you're getting? Would also be helpful to include the version of RMongo you're using.

Comment: @KumarDeepak Actually, I see there's a question that needs a relevant answer (which you've also commented on): [Querying RMongo with ObjectId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406329/querying-rmongo-with-objectid). I'll post an answer there ;-)

Comment: @KumarDeepak See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406329/querying-rmongo-with-objectid for an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had spent hours on this.