# Querying RMongo with ObjectId

Tags: r, rmongo

Is there a way to query in RMongo with an ObjectId?

Something like:

`results <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "users", "{'_id': 'ObjectId('5158ce108b481836aee879f8')'}")`

Perhaps by importing a bson library?

Comment: Any solution for RMongo. The two answers given are for different libraries.

Answer (score 3):

RMongo's `dbGetQuery()` function is expecting [MongoDB Extended JSON syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) for the provided query string.

The MongoDB Extended JSON equivalent of `ObjectId("<id>")` is `{ "$oid": "<id>" }`:

```
 results <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "users", "{'_id': { '$oid': '5158ce108b481836aee879f8' }}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had spent hours figuring this out. Is there any documentation where I can look up when stuck with issues like these?

Comment: There is some documentation included as part of the RMongo package (eg: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/RMongo.pdf), but it's a bit thin on details & examples. In general RMongo relies on standard MongoDB operators & Extended JSON syntax as described in the MongoDB manual (http://docs.mongodb.org). If you can't find an answer, I'd suggest asking a new question on StackOverflow (or perhaps add a bounty to an existing question that hasn't received enough attention).

Answer (score 1):

Try the new mongolite package:

```
library(mongolite)
m <- mongo("users")
m$find('{"_id":{"$oid":"5158ce108b481836aee879f8"}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

mongo.oid.from.string {rmongodb}

Create a mongo.oid object ftom a string
Package:  rmongodb
Version:  1.5.3
Description
Create from a 24-character hex string a mongo.oid object representing a MongoDB Object ID.

Usage
mongo.oid.from.string(hexstr)
Arguments
hexstr
(string) 24 hex characters representing the OID.
Note that although an error is thrown if the length is not 24, no error is thrown if the characters are not hex digits; you'll get zero bits for the invalid digits.

Details
See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Values

Comment: An answer for rmongo is needed.