# How to query a Document by ObjectId with rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

Here is what you get in mongo shell :

```
db.col.find(ObjectId("5571849db1969e0a6eb32731")).pretty()
{   
"_id" : ObjectId("5571849db1969e0a6eb32731"),
    "name" : "Some name",
    "logo" : "Some logo",
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("5571830031c7fc341bc2e105"),
        ObjectId("5571830031c7fc341bc2e107")
    ],
    "admins" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "steps" : 5782
}
```

Here is what I get in rmongo :

```
myResult <- mongo.find(Connexion, "db.col", query='ObjectId("5571849db1969e0a6eb32731")')

#Error in mongo.bson.from.JSON(arg) : 
#  Not a valid JSON content: ObjectId("5571849db1969e0a6eb32731")
```

So, how to do it right ?

Just in case : I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406329/querying-rmongo-with-objectid) already. But **mongolite** doesn't support authentication (which is therefore a no-go) and I don't understand what to do with the second answer. If I try

```
result <- mongo.find(Connexion, "db.col", query=mongo.oid.from.string("5571849db1969e0a6eb32731"))
```

I get

```
# Error in mongo.bson.from.argument(query) : Can't convert to bson: argument should be one of 'list', 'mongo.bson' or 'character'(valid JSON)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
result <- mongo.find(Connexion, "db.col", query=list('_id' = mongo.oid.from.string("5571849db1969e0a6eb32731")))
```

Comment: Yep I had finally understood that something like :
`[1] 0
attr(,"mongo.cursor")
<pointer: 0x326d750>
attr(,"class")
[1] "mongo.cursor"`  was not an error but a valid answer

Comment: Thanks a lot SIR.. for this answer @Dmitriy Selivanov